# requests.get gives me different header than devtools

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to create an auto-login bot using requests.

At some point I need to use `requests.get(URL)` to get a token and use that token for my next get, but I am not able to get the token.

My code:

```py
    import requests
    import time
    import urllib.request
    import json
    
    s = requests.Session()

    username = 'XXXX'
    password = 'XXXX'
    gameworld = 'XXXX'
    
    s.headers\['User-Agent'\] = "XXXX"
    
    s.headers\['Content-Type'\] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    s.headers\['X-Requested-With'\] = 'XMLHttpRequest'

    # get page cookies

    url = 'https://www.tribalwars.nl/'
    res = s.get(url)
    
    authurl = 'https://www.tribalwars.nl/page/auth'
    data = f"username={username}&password={password}&remember=1"
    res = s.post(authurl, data=data, allow_redirects=False)
    
    if res.status_code == 200:
        print("Logged in to account")
    else:
        print("Could not login")
    
    # log in to world
    
    url_gameworld = "https://www.tribalwars.nl/page/play/nl90"
    
    res = s.get(url_gameworld)
    print(res.headers)
```

This gives me the following result:

> {'Server': 'nginx', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0, private, must-revalidate, no-cache, private, public', 'Date': 'Sun, 08 Jan 2023 22:00:11 GMT', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'X-JoinUs': 'We are always searching for skilled admins and passionate coders! Go to career.innogames.com and mention this header in your application!', 'X-SaId': '494161', 'X-Frame-Options': 'NONE'}

Looking in devtools, the response header looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGAHv.png)

I expected the header returns 'uri': the token, but I'm not seeing that in my header.

Answer (score 0):

The request is automatically following a redirect that the server is sending. So the response you are viewing in the python `print` is the page that was redirected to. In the devtools screenshot, the response you are seeing is that intermediate request (you can see the response code 302) and the `location` header with the url is where they want the request to be redirected too. `requests` is just following that.

Comment: Thanks for the response
Does that mean i succesfully logged in? Also, if i use allow_redirects = False, i get response code 302, but my header still doesn't give me the token.

Comment: I don't know the semantics of the website's operation, and I don't have a login that will work to authenticate, so take this as an educated guess. The second request (the one you send login/password to) returns a 200 status code even in an error condition, so the check of the status code won't tell you if you are logged in. If you print the output of the second request when done with a valid login/pass/UA, you may get more information about how to determine login status.